# Objective C @property in .h file vs @property in .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOs Page based application template there is 2 different ways used to declare instance variable :

one is declared in .h (DataViewController.h) as :

```
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
```

the other is defined in .m as :

```
@interface ModelController()
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageData;
@end
```

Is there any difference / advantage or is it just some old vs some new syntax ?

Comment: what is '@Prototype' ? you mean class definition vs class extension which are not the same thing

Comment: @Daij-Djan made a mistypo it was '@Property of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@property you mean?

Putting your properties in the .m file makes them semi-private. That's known as an anonymous category, or class extension.

By doing that the interface that you define in the .m file is only (easily) visible within the scope of the .m file.

Objective C introspection means that nothing is truly private however.

I tend not to use class extensions because they are not visible to subclasses either. I use @private or @protected, as appropriate, and assume user's of my classes won't break the contract I've defined. If they do they do so at their own risk.

Comment: so Apple does not follow best practice by doing so ?

Comment: What makes you say that? Apple's frameworks are intended for public consumption by a diverse group of customers, so their frameworks are a perfect example where you WOULD want to use class extensions. I suggest you search in the Xcode docs on the string "Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation" and read the resulting section.

Comment: given this talks about properties... there is no way to declare them private/protected - thats only variables

Comment: True. I should have stuck with a discussion of properties, and not mixed in mention of instance variables. Thanks for pointing that out.